# Established TCP Communication terminates without any clue

Tags: networking, windows-server-2019, wireshark, tcpdump, rpc

I'm not able to understand what might be the reason for a lost TCP Communication over RPC between a CentOS 7 and Windows 2019 Server.

From the Wireshark I could see that the TCP Communication is established, and **RemoteCreateInstance Response** is not reaching its destination.

CentOS 7 - 172.18.19.140

Windows 2019 - 172.18.33.168

See the Wireshark images:

[image: Wireshark trace from Windows 2019 Server]

[image: Network Trace from CentOS 7]

What could be the reason for it..?

Where should I investigate ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the network layout between the 2 machines?
Your wireshark captures indicate problems - either with the ACKs getting through - or with the capture of ACKs.

Comment: You can see from the *CentOS 7 network trace*  RemoteCreateInstance Request ACK is reaching the CentOS system.. but the RemoteCreateInstance Response is not.

Comment: Absolutely. So I'm wondering if there are firewalls or other devices (either in hardware or software) that could be preventing ACKs from the Centos machine reaching the Windows machine?